# How find this sum $\sum_{k=1}^{n}[\arctan{f(k)}\arctan{g(k)}]$

Tags: calculus, summation

Let $n$ be a positive integer. Compute

> $$S_{n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left[\arctan{\left(\dfrac{k^2+k-1}{(k^2+k+2)(k^2+k+1)}\right)}\arctan{\left(\dfrac{k^4+2k^3+2k^2+k+2}{(2k^2+1)(k^2+k+1)}\right)}\right].$$

My try:
I think maybe this problem use this

> $$\arctan{x}-\arctan{y}=\arctan{\dfrac{x-y}{1+xy}}.$$

But I can't. Thank you for your help.

Comment: For the first term, did you notice that (-1 + k + k^2)/((1 + k + k^2) (2 + k + k^2)) = 3/(2 + k + k^2) - 2/(1 + k + k^2) ? I have no idea of what could be the use of that.

Comment: This answer has some really neat trick hidden in it or it is just evil.